# How to put Hash Map inside another

Tags: android, kotlin, hashmap, type-mismatch

I have this code

```
var mapForContent: HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Map<String, Any>>>? = null
val map = it.value as HashMap<String, Map<String, Any>>?

mapForContent?.put(i.toString(), mapForContent
```

but it gives me an error saying:

```
Type mismatch
```

Can anyone give me advice on how to solve this
Thank you :)

Comment: Could it be that you mixed some variables when you wrote your question? `map` is not used anymore and for `it` and `i` some information is missing... as it is written here you can't put the map (`mapForContent`) into itself as value... if you really need that you should not specify the map value type that explicitly... if you wanted to add `map` as value, remove the `?`... or add it to `mapForContent` value type if those value maps can be `null`, i.e. `var mapForContent : HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Map<String, Any>>?>?`...

Answer (score 0):

I just assume, that you tried to put `map` into mapForContent.

```
var mapForContent: HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Map<String, Any>>>? = null
val map = it.value as HashMap<String, Map<String, Any>>?
```

This is a type mismatch, as mapForContent should be

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Map<String, Any>>?>?
```

or map has to be

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Map<String, Any>>
```